# Send data from one android app to another without passing through a server

Tags: android, rest

Is it possible to create a kind of REST server with an android app so one user can directly POST data to another user using his IP address ?

Comment: No , another device. Like sending the data to a webserver but the webserver is another android app in another device

Comment: you are talking about sending through WiFi or Bluetooth right?

Comment: No about sending through internet, IP, HTTP POST/GET directly to the app...

Comment: https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd

Comment: You can indeed integrate a NanoHttpD server for that. But only if the server device is on wifi. Mobile connection not possible for server device.

Comment: the problem with using NanoHttpD is what if one of his phones is behind a nat box? He can't connect to a nat box IP address.

Comment: The server phone will have a wifi connection with a router indeed. The router must then forward the used port to the Android device. This has to be done in the router settings. For a travelling salesman thats not a nice solution. For the client phone there are none restrictions.